# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript' Heroku in Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to heroku but push to heroku is rejected due to: "Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'".
[I've also attached a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgEBW.png)

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
#Tooltips and popovers depend on tether for positioning
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My `application.js` looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

And my `application.scss` looks like this:

```
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 @import "bootstrap";
```

The application runs fine locally but I can't seem to push to heroku. I've already tried `rake assets:precompile` and committing the changes before pushing to heroku but still no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove  gems `jquery-rails, jquery-ui-rails`, Rails 5.1 use `rails-ujs` by default and not using `jquery`. Use yarn for install jquery - `yarn add jquery`. [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/)

Comment: I removed the two gems, removed lines containing `jquery` from `application.js` and `application.scss`, ran `yarn add jquery`, `bundle install`, ran `rake assets:precompile`, committed and pushed to heroku but I'm still getting the same error .

Comment: After adding jquery through yarn, you need to add the path to jquery in application.js, [here](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/yarn-rails/) is a small article on how to use yarn in rails 5.1

Comment: Simply adding `gem 'jquery-rails'` to the gemfile fixed this for me

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I don't believe that jquery an rails-ujs are the same. Moreover, why would you HAVE to use yarn here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have node modules to install, so you need to set multiple buildpacks in Heroku. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65677844/13721500

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment

Comment: I still haven't enough reputation points to add comments on others posts