# Can't push my project to Heroku...rake aborted Sprockets file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

so i'm trying to push my project onto Heroku but I keep running into this issue.

I've tried various different options and it still giving me the same error

The error is:

> > remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
> >     remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system. remote:
> >     Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install remote:        I,
> >     [2018-07-11T15:38:38.244799 #1469]  INFO -- : Writing
> >     /tmp/build_3216acb17a7c6513d0bbba80e51b87ec/public/assets/America_Latina_red.svg-81715f166cd02474df00ef6b91e8b614eee8c4b849a497d4b3d5f548b83fcd59.png
> >     remote:        I, [2018-07-11T15:38:38.263447 #1469]  INFO -- :
> >     Writing
> >     /tmp/build_3216acb17a7c6513d0bbba80e51b87ec/public/assets/magnifyingglass-f96713ba24099755cdd1bb1bb92c720b1136c87a85f437489a8cdb47e0f272af.png
> >     remote:        rake aborted! remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound:
> >     couldn't find file 'bulma-start/_javascript/main.js' with type
> >     'application/javascript' remote:        Checked in these paths:

it says Sprockets:FileNotFound...
everything is working locally. Also I'm using RoR

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have node dependencies so you're application should be running multiple buildpacks (ruby and nodejs). Here's how to define them using Heroku CLI:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs

git push heroku main
```

Find more details here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `bulma-start/_javascript/main.js` somewhere, but that file does not exist. Remove the bad reference.

Comment: If i comment out bulma-start from my application.js requirements, it does the same exact thing for jquery.

Comment: I commented out numerous requirements such as jquery, my bulma-start. It's just not compiling my node modules for some reason..

Answer (score -1):

My /node_modules were inside my .gitignore.
I removed node modules from .gitignore then in my terminal did:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then did git add . 
git commit - m "my message"
git push heroku master

That's why when heroku was precompiling it was getting an error.

Comment: This is not a great solution. More of a hack. 

Yarn is a package manager. Meaning the only thing you push to your remote is a package.json file containing the names and versions of software to use.  

Heroku reads your package.json file and installs yarn and uses your package.json file to go get the correct dependencies installed on the server. 

By removing 'node_modules' from the .gitignore file you are basically just uploading all the assets as you have them locally. Which defeates the purpose and bloats your git repository.